# How do I read ONE single status update, comment or like?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, message, feed

I have the read feed working and get back everything I should and it looks like the array listed below:

My problem is that I want to retrieve the individual message.  I've tried:

```
// what I think should work - fails
$msgData = $facebook->api("/$fb_id/posts/$msgToken", 'GET', $parameters);

// link in msg (below) but fb gives "unknown browser" error message
$msgData = file_get_contents("http://www.facebook.com/$fb_id/posts/$msgToken");

// as per fb docs but this fails too...
$msgData = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/$msgToken");
```

So, what's the real way to get just one message when you know that messages ID?

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 100002222222222_209088888888888
        [from] => Array
            (
                [name] => My dog
                [id] => 100002222222222
            )

        [message] => this is a test msg...
        [picture] => http://platform.ak.fbcdn.net/www/app_full_proxy.php?app=999999999999999...
        [link] => http://www.domain.com/
        [name] => Application Name
        [caption] => Caption of for this post
        [description] => A description of this post
        [icon] => http://www.facebook.com/images/icons/default_app_icon.gif
        [actions] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Comment
                        [link] => http://www.facebook.com/100002222222222/posts/209088888888888
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Like
                        [link] => http://www.facebook.com/100002222222222/posts/209088888888888
                    )

            )

        [privacy] => Array
            (
                [description] => Friends
                [value] => ALL_FRIENDS
                [allow] => 0
                [deny] => 0
            )
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access single post by post id which is `100002222222222_209088888888888` in sample provided by you. (post id is `"{$user_id}_${message_id}"`)

To to so you need also active `access_token`. If you using Facebook PHP-SDK it will use Logged-In user `access_token` (if you logged in to Facebook and user [`FB.login`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) or [`Facebook::getLoginUrl`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/))

```
$post_id = '100002222222222_209088888888888';
$msgData = $facebook->api("/{$post_id}");
```

otherwise you'll need to provide one manually:

```
$post_id = '100002222222222_209088888888888';
$access_token = "APPLICATION_OR_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN";

// Using Facebook PHP-SDK
$parameters = array('access_token'=>$access_token);
$msgData = $facebook->api("/{$post_id}", 'GET', $parameters);

// OR

// Using file_get_contents
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$post_id}?access_token={$access_token}";
$msgData = file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: yep... that was it!  I was using just the message id and leaving off the user_id.  Adding them both together with the underscore worked great and its the same with comments to the message: $msgToken = $user_id_$message_id_$comment_id;